# Magento: VAT of coupon (rebate) deducted from grand total?

Tags: settings, magento-1.4

My Magento somehow calcs VAT on my rebate and deducts that from the grand total, please take a look at the example below:

Sub total: 188 EUR
Rebate 10 EUR
Shipping 0 EUR 
Vat: 28,12 EUR (19%)
Total: 176,10 EUR

The grand total should be 178 EUR (188 -10), but its 188 - 10 - 1.90, which is wrong. Maybe something is not configured the right way, but I got no more ideas where to look. I already set 'Apply Customer Tax' to 'After Discount' in system > config > Tax, this is not the solution.

Any ideas?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your Magento version is below 1.4.2 then you're going to have a bad time. They did a huge rewrite of the tax calculations in the 1.4.2 version, which solved many problems.

Anyway, try this setup:

- Tax Calculation Method Based On: Total
- Apply Customer Tax: Before discount
- Apply Discount On Prices: Including tax

Let me know how it works.

Comment: If I set it up your way, it calcs the VAT based on the subtotal (188 EUR), thats wrong, too. The good thing is, the grand total is correct now. Unfortunately, thats not enough for my customer. Any ideas?